# Change relabel-config key Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I work with Dockerswarm and want to change key label to more convenient label on query prometheus. let say I have:

```
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name="service_1"}
```

I want to change the label from `container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name` to `service_name`. What I try to achieve is query with something like this.

```
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{service_name="service_1"}
```

I do walkaround and try some suggestions like this:

```
- source_labels: [__meta_dockerswarm_service_name,container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name]
  regex: (.+)
  target_label: service_name
```

but the result when query PromQL, its not the same as `container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name` does. Did I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the `container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name` label is generated from the `__meta_dockerswarm_container_label_*` label (see the list of available labels during `dockerswarm_sd_configs` target discovery in [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs.html#dockerswarm_sd_configs) ).

The following relabeling rule could be used for generating such a label:

```yaml
- action: labelmap
  regex: __meta_dockerswarm_(.+)
```

If you want copying this label to `service_name` label, then just add the following relabeling rule to the end of existing relabeling rules:

```yaml
- source_labels:
  - __meta_dockerswarm_container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name
  target_label: service_name
```

Note that the `container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name` label will remain in scraped metrics. If you need removing this label, then add the following relabeling rule:

```yaml
- action: labeldrop
  regex: container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name
```

See [relabeling cookbook](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/relabeling.html) for more practical examples.

Comment: hi @valyala. thank you for answering. This relabeling config for copying does not work. service_name on query just showing `cadvisor` instead of label service name like `container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name`

Comment: on alert rules, service_name does not show at labels too